# How to get the return value from a powershell scriptblock started in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I try to get a return value from a powershell scriptblock started with new Process in c#.

```
    Process powershellProcess = null;
try
{
    powershellProcess = new Process();
    powershellProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
    powershellProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-EncodedCommand {0}", isEnabledBase64String);
    powershellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    powershellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
    powershellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    powershellProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    powershellProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    bool value = powershellProcess.Start();
    powershellProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    while (!powershellProcess.HasExited)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    powershellProcess.CancelOutputRead();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    powershellProcess.Close();
}
```

E.g. the scriptblock "isEnabledBase64String" returns a number.
How do I get to the number? Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Workaround:
If powershellProcess.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived is used one can just uses Write-Host xxx and gets it in OnOutputDataReceived.
Disadvantage: Its a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to start a process to execute the powershell script? You can use powershell instance object from the System.Management.Automation.

See example at windows powershell from c#
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

this will give you much more control over execution of script, passing the param as well as reading the output.

Comment: Yep. Because afterwards I redirect 
powershellProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
powershellProcess.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
and catch output data received